# Combine sort and filter function of primefaces column not working

Tags: sorting, jsf-2, primefaces, filtering

I'm new JSF. I have a datatable which contains some columns have both of sort and filter functions. But I encounter a problem when I execute action chains:

1. Filter column
2. Click sort on this column
3. Delete first row, another row is deleted instead of first row.

If you click sort again on this column, everything will be ok. My datatable is:

```
            <p:dataTable id="mainTable" var="entry"
                value="#{manageUsers.users}" paginator="true"
                rows="10" dynamic="true" paginatorPosition="bottom"
                paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport} {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink}"
                loadingMessage="... now loading ..." style="overflow: auto;">

                <f:facet name="header">
                    <div class="tableTitle">#{msg['general.data.users']}</div>
                </f:facet>

                <!-- specific fields -->
                <p:column sortBy="#{entry.userId}" filterBy="#{entry.userId}" filterStyle="width:70px">
                    <f:facet name="header">#{msg['user.userId']}</f:facet>
                    <h:outputText value="#{entry.userId}" />
                </p:column>
                <p:column sortBy="#{entry.userName}" filterBy="#{entry.userName}">
                    <f:facet name="header">#{msg['user.userName']}</f:facet>
                    <h:outputText value="#{entry.userName}" />
                </p:column>
                <p:column sortBy="#{entry.group.groupId}" filterBy="#{entry.group.groupId}" filterStyle="width:70px">
                    <f:facet name="header">#{msg['usergroup.groupid']}</f:facet>
                    <h:outputText value="#{entry.group.groupId}" />
                </p:column>                                                                                         
                <!-- action buttons -->
                <p:column>
                    <f:facet name="header"><h:outputText value="&#160;&#160; #{msg['actions']} &#160;&#160;"/></f:facet>
                    <h:panelGroup>
                        <p:commandButton action="#{manageUsers.editUser(entry)}"
                            update=":editForm,:mainForm:bindingPanel" icon="ui-icon ui-icon-pencil"
                            oncomplete="editDialog.show();" title="edit" 
                            disabled="#{!userSession.canUserAccess('ADMIN','WRITE')}"/>
                        <p:commandButton
                            action="#{manageUsers.selectUser(entry)}" onclick="confirmDelete.show()"
                            update=":mainForm:bindingPanel"
                            icon="ui-icon ui-icon-close" title="mark for deletion" 
                            disabled="#{!userSession.canUserAccess('ADMIN','WRITE')}"/>
                        <p:commandButton action="#{manageUsers.selectUser(entry)}" update=":mainForm:bindingPanel"
                            icon="ui-icon ui-icon-person" title="manage user bindings"
                            rendered="#{entry.isInRole('APPROVER')}" />
                    </h:panelGroup>
                </p:column>
            </p:dataTable>
```

Could please tell me what root cause? Thank you

Comment: Your datatable is missing the `rowKey` attribute. That attribute should be set to a unique identifier on your `entry` entity. It's how the datatable can identify and select the correct row on selection

Comment: thank for your help, @kolossus. But problem still occur. I feel that data of table is not the same between before sorting and after sorting.